# Row Number for RDLC Matrix

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, matrix, rdlc

I am using RDLC Matrix. Total number of record i got from data set is 46 which matrix map to 7 records.I am using following expression to count number of rows which not working as i expected.

```
   =RowNumber(nothing)
```

[image: result of matrix]

Comment: Can you clarify how you expect it to work? From the documentation, RowNumber(Nothing) gives running row number in outermost data region - it means it gives you the row number of the last data source row that is used for this matrix row. If you want your row number column to show numbers from 1 to 7, then maybe you can add new column in your dataset that would contain that number. It would be easy to do since it is grouped by student name.

Comment: i want to display count of matrix not rows of dataset

Comment: Then the suggested approach should work - adding new column with your row number in data source would be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
=RowNumber(Nothing)/Count(Fields!AdmitCardNo.Value)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! you save my time